# Update table from hierarchy function - SAP HANA

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, hierarchy, hana

Been struggling with this - hope someone can help...

I have created a scalar user-defined function (UDF) in SAP HANA Studio which is supposed to return a "Knudebeskrivelse" (node-description) from a hierarchy - based on inputs `PROFITCENTER` and `HIERARCHY_LEVEL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_KNUDEBESKRIVELSE_ON_REQUESTED_LEVEL
(IN PROFITCENTER NVARCHAR (40)
,IN HIERARCHY_LEVEL_INPUT INT)

returns KNUDEBESKRIVELSE NVARCHAR (40)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE KNUDEBESKRIVELSE NVARCHAR(40);

SELECT
"Knudebeskrivelse" INTO KNUDEBESKRIVELSE
        
    FROM HIERARCHY_ANCESTORS (
    SOURCE HIERARCHY (
        SOURCE (
            select "Knude-ID" AS node_id, "ID for overordnet" as parent_id, * FROM "FRS_PRO244"."GAAA_FKO"
            )
            CACHE FORCE
            )
START WHERE "Knudenavn" = PROFITCENTER
            )
WHERE HIERARCHY_LEVEL = HIERARCHY_LEVEL_INPUT
;

END
;
```

Using that function, I want to update the field `MYNDIGHED` in table `AP_MYNDIGHED` - taking the value `PROFITCENTER` from `AP_MYNDIGHED`, and the `HIERARCHY_LEVEL` (so far I've just hard coded '2' - will be changed later) as below:

```
UPDATE FRS_PRO244.AP_MYNDIGHED
SET MYNDIGHED = "FRS_PRO244"."GET_KNUDEBESKRIVELSE_ON_REQUESTED_LEVEL"(AP_MYNDIGHED.PROFITCENTER, 2)
```

The function is created and runs without error messages, but the field `MYNDIGHED` is not updated - or rather, it's being nulled...

I suspect the issues lies with the return value being null due to some error in the function, but I'm not sure how to test and resolve this.

I've tried creating a similar table UDF, which returns the requested value just fine... Problem here is that I don't know how to use the table function result in the set-statement.

Anyways, probably some basic error (I'm not very experienced with this) - hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working after all - this function code does the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_KNUDEBESKRIVELSE_ON_REQUESTED_LEVEL_SCALAR
(IN PROFITCENTER NVARCHAR (40)
,IN HIERARCHY_LEVEL_INPUT INT)

returns KNUDEBESKRIVELSE_OUT NVARCHAR(40)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE KNUDEBESKRIVELSE NVARCHAR(40);

SELECT KNUDEBESKRIVELSE INTO KNUDEBESKRIVELSE_OUT
FROM HIERARCHY_ANCESTORS (
SOURCE HIERARCHY (
SOURCE (
select "Knude-ID" AS node_id, "ID for overordnet" as parent_id, "Knudebeskrivelse" AS KNUDEBESKRIVELSE, "Knudenavn" as KNUDENAVN FROM "FRS_PRO244"."GAAA_FKO"
)
CACHE FORCE
)
START WHERE KNUDENAVN = PROFITCENTER
)
WHERE HIERARCHY_LEVEL = HIERARCHY_LEVEL_INPUT
;
  
END;
```

Seems I might have introduced some confusion in the code with naming of the variable `'KNUDEBESKRIVELSE'`...